# Changing EditRowStyle programmatically when Edit is clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, editing

I have an ASP.NET(2.0 using C#) web app, in which I have a gridview. I have an Edit column in it, but I'm not using the regular Edit functionality. When Edit is clicked something else happens.

I wanted to know how to change the style of the row in which Edit was clicked in the `GridView_RowEditing` function?

I have tried this:

```
    protected void Grid_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
     Grid.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Groove;
     //Do some Other things 
    }
```

When I click it, the other functionality works, but the style doesn't change. All I want to do is to change the style of the editRow so that I can tell which one it is.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you be more specific than "didn't work"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, you can setup a particular style for SelectedItem in the GridView. Then when the edit button is clicked, you can do this -

```
grdView.SelectedIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
```

After doing this, the row in edit mode will get selected and the "SelectedItem" style will be applied to it.